Birational K3 surfaces
In Shafarevich Basic Algebraic Geometry I, there is a theorem (p.39 Theorem 5)
"Any Irreducible closed set is birational to a hypersurface of some affine space".
Hence, a projective K3 surface is birational to a hypersurface $X$ in $\mathbb P^3$.

Is the degree of $X$ necessarily four?


Not necessarily. Take your favorite K3 surface $X'$ of degree $2d$ in $\mathbb{P}^N$ and let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ be its general linear projection. Then $X'$ is birational to $X$ and $X$ is a (usually non-normal) surface of the same degree $2d$ as $X'$.

Dear Sasha, I wonder what happens when $d=1$? I.e., for K3 surface arising from double cover of $\mathbb P^2$ branched along a sextic curve, is there still a birational morphism to a hypersurface of $\mathbb P^3$?

A polarization of degree 2 is not very ample, but after multiplication by 3 it becomes very ample, so using this polarization you can embed the K3 surface into $\mathbb{P}^{10}$ and then project to $\mathbb{P}^3$ to a surface of degree 18.
